# driver.findelements(by.xpath()) returning zero

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find out the no. of orders in the following picture using
      `//*[@id='past-orders-tab']/div[contains(@class,'physical')]`
       [image]

but it is returning zero using `.size()`  ( storing in List[WebElement])
.When i picked one order using `findelement()` ,it is working fine. Here's the page source code [image]

How to correct it?

Comment: By.xpath("past_orderbox") --- This xpath does not make sense. Is the past_orderbox a variable containing the xpath u have written earlier. If so remove double quotes.

Comment: i should have read from .properties file. Thanks @Grasshopper

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until there is at least one element present on a web page as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
List<WebElement> ord = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("#past-orders-tab > div.physical")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but one question , can the path be converted into cssSelector like you did. It is a flipkart website

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you are asking?? Do you want any method to explicitly convert xpath to cssSelector??

Comment: @bot13 If I'm right there is no any method to convert xpath to cssSelector, you need to [learn how to make a cssSelector from some tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and try with yourself. Thanks

Comment: yes because  i haven't seen this kind of cssxpath before

Comment: Follow this tutorial to learn about cssSelector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: It's not an XPath, it's a CSS selector. It's another way of locating elements. You should use CSS selectors when possible because they are faster but there are some things that CSS selectors cannot do... in those cases use XPath.